# How to align ggmap CRS of google map longitude latitude

Tags: r, ggmap, r-sf

Despite the many posts of CRS projections, etc I cannot stop my town from sinking.

If I go to [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps) and enter `-35.016, 117.878` the town of Albany is on dry land (as per following image): 
[image]

If I enter the lat/long into R and try to map using the simple features package and ggmap, the town is in the ocean:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(lwgeom) 
library(ggmap) 

lat <- c(-35.016)
lon <- c(117.878)
df <- tibble(lon,lat) %>% st_as_sf( coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

bbox_aus <- c(left = 113.338953078, bottom = -43.6345972634, right = 153.569469029, top = -10.6681857235)
ggmap_aus <- ggmap(get_stamenmap(bbox_aus, zoom = 5, maptype = "toner-background"))  

ggmap_aus + 
  geom_sf(data = df, colour = "red" , size = 3,  alpha = 0.5, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
 # coord_sf(datum = sf::st_crs(4326)) +
  labs(title = "Albany Sinking",
       x = NULL,
       y = NULL) +
   theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you use `geom_point()` with the lon and lat as x and y.

```
df <- tibble(lon,lat) %>% st_as_sf( coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326,
                                    remove = FALSE)

ggmap_aus + 
  geom_point(data = df, colour = "red", size = 3,  alpha = 0.5,
             aes(x = lon, y = lat)) +
  # coord_sf(datum = sf::st_crs(4326)) +
  labs(title = "Albany is saved",
       x = NULL,
       y = NULL) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/336#issuecomment-339500115), using `geom_point()` with an x and y aesthetic aligns more closely with how ggmap produces a ggplot.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to make it work with `geom_sf()`, which plots using the `geometry` column. There's some discussion in that linked comment, but the solution seems to be to use `inherit.aes = FALSE`, which you've already tried.

Based on the warning `Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.`, I assume that the ggmap object has some coordinate system that is not 4326, but I couldn't find how to access it. I did try reprojecting `df` to EPSG: 3857, but that did not work.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene for saving Albany!!!.  Still slightly curious to understand why geom_sf didn't work but not enough to continue investigating. Really happy to have this solution and will stick with geom_point :-)